# Is RadioTap field sent from wireless card or Is just a report that is created from wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

Hello i've question about **RadioTap field** in wireless connections.

Is this field **sent** from wireless card or Is just a report that is created from wireshark like "**frame 3 field**" under the "**frame II section**" in wired connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Radiotap headers are a way for the 802.11 card to attach per-packet radio metadata to each packet it receives, and pass that information up to the sniffer. It is not information that was transmitted over the air. It's just a way for the radio to tell the sniffer useful things like what channel the radio was tuned to when it received the frame, how strong the signal was, what modulation and coding scheme was used, etc.